# Add comma separator in react native numbers

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am building a react native application that involves dealing with numbers, my issue is I want a comma separator on the numbers i.e. instead of 1000 I want it to show 1,000. I am able to use `.toLocaleString()` and it works fine in development but when I build the app apk the `.toLocaleString()` method seems to be ignored. How do I go about this? Is there any better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `Intl.NumberFormat`, but getting `Intl` to work in React Native can be a pain in the butt. so personally, I'd just do it myself using a regex, like so

```
function formatWithCommas(n) { 
  return n.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, ","); 
}
```